# Advanced typescript inference of 1 object structure into another object structure

Tags: typescript

## The scenario

I have an object which defines some configuration for some data that needs to be resolved. The object contains classes + string names of methods that exist on those classes

```
{
  orders: {
    service: OrderService, // The class
    serviceMethod: 'getOrders' // The method name which exists on the class
  },
  cart: {
    service: OrderService,
    serviceMethod: 'getCart'
  }
}
```

The class looks like this

```
export class OrderService {
  public getOrders = (): Observable<Order[]> = {
    return of([ {id: '1', name: 'Order 1' ])
  };

  public getCart = (): Observable<Cart> => {
    return of({ products: [] })
  };
}
```

Once the config has been executed, the resolved data looks like this:

```
{
  orders: [ {id: '1', name: 'Order 1' ], // Data of type Order[]
  cart: { products: [] } // Data of type Cart
}
```

## The issue

I'm trying to automatically infer the type of the resolved data based on the resolver configuration. I have this type, but even though the `T[P]['serviceMethod'] extends keyof T[P]['service']` should ensure that `T[P]['serviceMethod']` is a key of the provided class, it doesn't recognise it

Here is a StackBlitz of the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9yqbuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.interface.ts

If anyone can fix this, I'd be MASSIVELY grateful :)

```
export interface ResolverResource<TService = any> {
   service: Type<TService>;
   serviceMethod: keyof TService;
}

export type ResolvedData<T, TService = any> = {
   // Check if T[P] is a ResolverResource
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ResolverResource<TService>

      // Check if T[P]['serviceMethod'] exists on T[P]['service']
      ? T[P]['serviceMethod'] extends keyof T[P]['service']

         // Check if T[P]['service'][T[P]['serviceMethod']] is a function that returns an Observable
         // and infer the output type of the Observable
         ? T[P]['service'][T[P]['serviceMethod']] extends (...args: any[]) => Observable<infer U>
            ? U
            : never

         : never // Here is where it fails. It doesn't recognize that T[P]['serviceMethod'] is a key of T[P]['service']

      : never;
};
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs to clearly demonstrate the issue; the snippet here has undeclared types/values, and the stackblitz you linked looks a lot bigger than needed (and even if it were the right size, it needs to be here as plaintext to count as a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: @jcalz thank you. My code depends on RXJS and a type from Angular. Would a Github project be preferable to the StackBlitz?

Comment: The relevant code needs to be completely included as plaintext in the question itself.  Stack Overflow questions need to be self contained and not require that people navigate away from the site in order to understand the question.  I doubt that you require multiple files to demonstrate your issue, that almost certainly wouldn't be *minimal*; you might want to build up a small demonstration from scratch. You might want to review the guidelines for [ask] and what makes a [mre].  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz looks like all the relevant code is in the question? Would be very unreasonable to expect the entire type declarations from Angular and RXJS in plaintext..... Stackblitz also has a download feature if you wanted to use your own IDE?

Comment: @MattHope The SO guidelines at [ask] are fairly explicit about this.  I’m not asking for external libraries to be included as plaintext; either the question really depends on them, in which case we should edit the tags to include them… or the question does not really depend on them in which case a [mre] would replace them with something else.  Anyway if you think there’s enough information in the post to answer it, please go ahead and do so. I’m not going to downvote or otherwise interfere (aside from comments, that is)

Answer (score 2):

Starting to think there is a limitation in typescript to infer the explicit types from the Observable when using `keyof`. The docs imply that it'll always output the Union of all keys.

Doing the following gets your code to compile but both the orders and carts properties will be a union of each other.

```
export type ResolvedData<T, TService = any> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ResolverResource<TService>
    ?
      // You were missing this part, as 'keyof' Type<T> doesnt bring back the keys in the generic constraint
      T[P]['service'] extends Type<infer U>
        ?
          T[P]['serviceMethod'] extends keyof U
            ?
              U[T[P]['serviceMethod']] extends (
                ...args: any[]
              ) => Observable<infer V>
                ? V
                : never
            : never
        : never
    : never;
};
```

this gives you something like:

```
const resolvedData: ResolvedData<typeof resourceConfig> = {
  orders: [],
  cart: { products: [] },
};

// resolvedData.orders == Cart | Order[]
// resolvedData.cart == Cart | Order[]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. That's a huge step forward! Will continue and try to build on that